# Weird Issue With Internet connection

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04, firewall

I am facing an weird internet connectivity issue on my Ubuntu 19.04. My network services provider constantly denying on it and it occurring randomly and I am experiencing this on my office network as well. Very often, whenever I am navigating to some site, my `chrome` giving me error instantly:

```
This site can’t be reached
www.linuxbabe.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

and following few seconds, suddenly page content getting loaded and displayed.`

This is happenning almost all of my sites I'm visiting and I can't figure out where I have misconfigured anything.

**Update:** It appears this happens if I have `trickled` daemon installed. My `trickled` configuration(`/etc/trickled.conf`):

```
# this file is an example for a system-wide or personal settings file 
# for trickle (see manual pages for trickle, trickled and trickled.conf
# below are two examples that should be self-explaining

[ssh]
Priority = 1
Time-Smoothing = 0.1
Length-Smoothing = 2
[ftp]
Priority = 7
Time-Smoothing = 5
Length-Smoothing = 20
[bittorrent]
Priority = 8
[www]
Priority = 2
[https]
Priority = 3
[http]
Priority = 4
```

Any clues whether I have any misconfiguration, in these?

Comment: This means you have some problems in network connection. It is unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Try a different browser other than Chrome, like Firefox.